# How to use VSCode to debug Google Cloud Functions with Firestore triggers?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that runs on an onCreate trigger of my database, and when it runs it accesses other portions of the database to modify a tree of documents based on the one that was just created.

To test this function appropriately it needs to have a database full of information to run against, rather than just one document to modify.

Is there a way to provide the local emulator with a database full of data?

Even better, is there a way to attach a debugger directly to the cloud function and debug live functions (something like [this article](https://medium.com/@mwebler/debugging-firebase-functions-with-vs-code-3afab528bb36), but for firestore instead of firebase)?

Answer (score 0):

I the only way to provide the local emulator with a database full of data is creating one real database with dummy information.

There is an emulator under development which does implement some functions but it is in [alpha state](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator). Seems it is open source and it is hosted in Github. I suggest you to request testing its functionality. It's not sure it fulfills all the functionalities you need, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functions emulator. There is ver little documentation, but this is a good start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

```
$ npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator`

$ functions start

$ functions deploy api --trigger-http --timeout 600s

$ functions inspect api --port 9229
```

Create a VS Launce config:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach",
  "port": 9229 
}
```

Now you can F5 to start debugging.

This will **not** receive triggers from your database automatically, but it still very helpful as you can use an http request to trigger functions and debug them.

**Tip**: add this script to your `package.json` so you can easily `npm run debug` to build and deploy to the emulator:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "debug": "npm run build && functions deploy api --trigger-http --timeout 600s && functions inspect api --port 9229"` 
}
```